# Where can I find some "real time" discussion forums for security issues?

Tags: virus

The place where I work was hit by the new Qakbot variant (3rd generation) a couple of days ago and it has been brutal. Unfortunately a lot of the documentation out there is from the 1st iteration of this virus.

We've looked at a lot of the big antivirus sites (Symantec, McAffee, etc.) but unfortunately they are a little slow in getting their documentation up.

I'm looking for some online discussion forums or sites (simliar to here) where people would be discussing this issue in more "real time" so that we can look for some alternative plans of attack.

Can anybody recommend some sites for this? Interestingly enough, I have been doing some searches via Twitter as well, with limited results.

Comment: What is your issue whit this site?

Comment: I see you haven't even tried posing your issue as an actual question on this site.  Care to give it a try?

Comment: @WZeberaFFS and @Iszi have a point - what benefit does "real time" get you that a quick, specific answer from this site doesn't? That said, this question as it stands now isnt really on topic for this site. If you wanted to discuss shortcomings of the site - then we can move this to http://meta.security.stackexchange.com. Otherwise we'd probably close this... or you can ask in the chatroom :)

Comment: Questions asking for referrals to other communities that serve the same purpose as this one are not on topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try in our chatroom, at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/it-security.
Depending on hour of day / day of week, you may not find many people there... as it is, the regulars are not a huge crowd... but hopefully that will grow, along with the site.

Comment: Must say i have to agree whit @Ormis

Answer (score 4):

The best "real-time" discussion method, in my honest opinion, is IRC.  They're are so many IRC servers/rooms that it's hard to actually just give you a list.  I know that I started out on the [hak5 IRC](http://www.hak5.org/w/index.php/IRC) and i'm sure those guys will give you their favorites.  I don't really hang out in any enterprise-oriented IRC channels, but I know that there are a lot of options.